# Polymerization of propene chemical equation

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

What is the equation to represent the polymerization of propene?

It has to be in the form of general formula:

$$\ce{H-R-OH + H-R-OH -> H-R-R-OH + H2O}$$

I have this so far:
$$\ce{CH3-CH=CH2-OH + CH3-CH=CH2-OH -> ...  + H2O}$$

I'm confused as to how this reaction would work.

Comment: What do either of your equations have to do with propene?

Comment: 4 bonds of a carbon atom should be enough, don't you think ? BTW, others are confused as well, as propene polymerization does not work this way. It is not polycondensation.

Comment: The enol form of propaldehyde .... no, you gone up to a very wrong start. Grab your textbook, and try again after reading it once more!

Comment: Propene condenses to give [Polypropylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polypropylene), but your question body asks something very different from the title...

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb   Propene polymerizes to PP, (poly)condensation assumes elimination of small molecules like water.

Answer (score 2):

Propene performs radical ( denoted by $\cdot$ ) driven polymerization:

$$\ce{R. + CH2=CH(CH3) -> R-CH2-CH(CH3).}$$

where the radical end is eventually terminated by recombination,stopping the polymerization. Polymerizations typically convert a double bond of a monomer to a single bond, freeing extra electrons to create extra bonds between monomers.

OTOH, polycondensation eliminates small molecules like water from atoms of bonding functional groups, like :

Polyethylene terephthalate ( PET ) production eliminates water molecules :

$$\ce{R-COOH + HO-CH2-CH2-OH + HOOC-C6H4-COOH \\-> R-CO-O-CH2-CH2-O-CO-C6H4-COOH + 2 H2O}$$

Similarly polycarbonate eliminate hydrogen chloride ( that is immediately neutralized by hydroxide):

$$\ce{R-OH + COCl2 + HO-dian-OH ->[NaOH] R-O-CO-O-dian-OH + 2 HCl}$$